# class classname(value); & class classname=value; difference when constructor is explicit

Tags: c++, constructor, implicit

When constructor is explicit, it isn't used for implicit conversions. In the given snippet, constructor is marked as `explicit`. Then why in case `foo obj1(10.25);` it is working and in `foo obj2=10.25;` it isn't working ?

```
#include <iostream>
class foo
{
    int x;
    public:
    explicit foo( int x ):x(x)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    foo obj(10.25);  // Not an error. Why ?
    foo obj2 = 10.25; // Error
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**error:** error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'double' to 'foo'

Comment: You failed to tell us what "it isn't working" means. What is the error?

Comment: Related to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between these two lines of code.  The first line,

```
foo obj(10.25);
```

explicitly calls your `foo` constructor passing in `10.25`.  This syntax, in general, is a constructor call.

The second line,

```
foo obj2 = 10.25;
```

tries to implicitly convert from `10.25` to an object of type `foo`, which would require use of an implicit conversion constructor.  In this example, you've marked the constructor `explicit`, there's no implicit conversion constructor available, and so the compiler generates an error.

Comment: You missed part of the story.  There's a conversion from double to int going on before the constructor is called.  It's implicit but I think the compiler is required to issue a warning?  Most do at any rate.

Answer (score 3):

These two forms of initialization are technically different.  The first (`foo obj(10.25);`) is called direct initialization.  The second (`foo obj = 10.25;`) is called copy initialization.

`explicit` constructors can only be used when you explicitly initialize an object.  Direct initialization is one form of explicitly initializing an object.  The other form of explicit initialization is the use of a cast.

Comment: So, in direct initialization it doesn't matter if constructor is explicit ?

Comment: @Mahesh: Direct initialization is explicit construction.

Answer (score 1):

Your "not an error" case is an explicit construction. The compiler is doing what you told it to do.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are *not* implicitly converting `10.25` to `foo`. You are converting it to an `int`, so it's not an error. Saying `foo obj(10.25)` is regarded as a direct call to the constructor to initialize a `foo` object.

In the second case, you *are* trying to implicitly convert `10.25` to a `foo`. The constructor marked `explicit` will not be considered (as you rightfully say), and therefor you will get an error.

Comment: "Why would it be an error? You are implicitly converting the 10.25 to an int. You aren't implicitly converting it to a foo." Huh?